# how could i handle this linq query and compare it with and int in an if-statement?

Tags: c#, linq

i have the following code:

```
 int selectedcourseId = Convert.ToInt32(c1.Text);
 var cid = (from g in re.Sections where g.CourseID == selectedcourseId select g.CourseID); 

int selectedinstructorid = Convert.ToInt32(c2.Text);
var iid = (from u in re.Sections where u.InstructorID == selectedinstructorid select u.InstructorID);
```

i want to compare the two (selectedcourseId) with (cid) and (selectedinstructorid) with (iid) in if-statement such as:

```
  if (selectedcourseId = cid && selectedinstructorid = iid)
           {
                MessageBox.Show("it already exists");
           }
```

i have tried many things that didnt work our because i have limited knowledge.
thank you very much in advance for any comment or answer

Comment: Change `=` to `==` in if statement

Comment: i did it but it still doesnt work and shows:
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int?>'

Comment: @TimSchmelter i am new to the linq query and entity framework

Comment: For your System.Linq.IQueryable<int?> objects you can use the Value member, i.e. iid.Value and cid.Value. These can however be null (as they are nullable ints). You can check for value with HasValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code as: *(but it is meaningless for your situation to check this)*

```
 if (selectedcourseId == cid.First() && selectedinstructorid == iid.First())
```

First of all for checking equality in if statement you must use `==`, not `=`. And the second is the `IQueryable<T>` allows you to execute a query against a specific data source, but it uses deferred execution. For executing it in your case, you can use `First()`.

***But, I suggest that you are just learning how to use LINQ and therefore you have written this code.***

I don't know what you are trying to achive. But, if you want to search if there is any result with that ID's, the you must use `Any()`:

```
var result1 = from g in re.Sections where g.CourseID == selectedcourseId select g.CourseID;
var result2 = from u in re.Sections where u.InstructorID == selectedinstructorid select u.InstructorID;

if(result1.Any() && result2.Any()) { ... }
```

Or, if you want to find if there is any row which has specified `CourseID` and `InstructorID`, then you can call one `Any()`:

```
 if(re.Sections.Any(x => x.CourseID == selectedcourseId && x.InstructorID == selectedinstructorid))  
 { ... }
```

Comment: Why? That makes no sense to compare. It's already part of the `Where()` filter.

Comment: @r.hamd Be careful. This almost certainly hasn't actually fixed your problem. It has just allowed it to compile.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I suggest that he is just trying to learn how to use LINQ

Comment: What's the point of the following: `var x = 1; if (x == 1) { ... }`? That's exactly the sort of thing you're doing.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I don't know you, but while learning some new technologies some people may try such things. Imagine, you have tried this and this is not working and you can't find what is the problem. What would you do?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev which one of you your solutions has a better performance specialy speed?

Comment: @r.hamd Of course, second one. It just checks if there is any row with that data. Bur, `First()` is returning first row which specfies the condtion.

Comment: @r.hamd if you want to find if there is any row which has specified `CourseID` and `InstructorID`, then you can call ona `Any()` as in my update

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev brother would you check this question please for me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957645/how-to-handle-the-output-of-this-linq-querylist-and-out-each-object-in-a-tex

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to find the `X` from this [`XY-problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I guess you want to check if there is already a combination of courseid + instructorid. Then use a single query:

```
var data = from   section in re.Sections 
           where  section.InstructorID == selectedinstructorid
             &&   section.CourseID == selectedcourseId
           select section;
if(data.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("it already exists");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it in two queries, because the two results might be related to two different rows. This would lead to "false positives" when an instructor handles *some* section, and a course has *some* instructors, but the two matches do not belong to the same row:

```
course instructor
------ ----------
   100       10
   101       15
   102       20
```

If you are looking for a combination `(101, 10)` it is not enough to see that `100` is present and `10` is present; you need to check that the two belong to the same row in order to consider it a duplicate.

You can fix this by making a "check presence" query, like this:

```
var existing = re.Sections
    .Any(s => s.InstructorID == selectedinstructorid  && s.CourseID == selectedcourseId);
if (existing) {
    MessageBox.Show("it already exists");
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `bool existing = ...` or  `var existing = ...`

Comment: @ThomasLielacher You are right, I started with count, then went to `Any`, and forgot to fix the type. All the more reasons to use `var` :-)

Comment: @r.hamd "doesn't work" is a rather general description. Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it detect rows that are not there? Does it miss rows that are present?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight pretty good brother ,now its working brother

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (selectedcourseId = cid && selectedinstructorid = iid)
```

this will not work, since single '=' is an assignment, not a comparation (which is '==')

also, you can try to do something like this

```
var cid = (int)((from g in re.Sections where g.CourseID == selectedcourseId select g.CourseID).FirstOrDefault());
```

so you select the first or default record from your list and cast it to int